# How to make the SKBitmap bitmap color as Transparent in SkiaSharp

Tags: 2d, skia, skiasharp

In System.Drawing we will make the bitmap image color as transparent by using maketransparent method Whether SKBITMAP has any other equivalent method for making the color to transparent.

`Bitmap imgData = new Bitmap()
imgData.MakeTransparent(Color.White);`//in system.Drawing

Can any one please suggest a solution for making the color as transparent for SkiaSharp.SKBitmap

Comment: Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `SKBitmap.Pixels` does the trick.
Here is an extension method:

```cs
public static void ClearToTransparent (this SKBitmap bitmap) {
    int pixelCount = bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height;
    SKColor[] colors = new SKColor[pixelCount];
    SKColor transparent = new SKColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int n = 0; n < pixelCount; n++) {
        colors[n] = transparent;
    }
    bitmap.Pixels = colors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest asking on the official skia forums:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/skia-discuss

I know a quite a bit about skia, but they know everything. SkiaSharp is just a thin wrapper around the native library, so whatever they do just do the same in C#.

Comment: Hi @matthew Thank you for your update.I have already the posted the above in the provided forum.Kindly refer the link below. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-discuss/sn8Qxhw5Ckw